# Customizing snippets not working on Rstudio

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, tidyverse, code-snippets

To reduce the workload of inputing the pipelines %>%, I set up a snippet in Rstudio:

```
snippet pipe
         %>%
```

But it's not working. I am not sure whether I forgot something?

Comment: Are you aware of Ctrl+Shift+M  :-)

Comment: @DanChaltiel, yes I am. But I prefer using snippet, perhaps because I am using Apple keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are a Mac User you could also use `Shift+Command+M`. I use MacOS myself and think it is really convenient.